# Eclipse " scanner.ensureopen() line not available "

Tags: java

I'm learning to work with oriented objects and i'm stuck with this error that throws me eclipse when it arrives to the final of my main class. The thing is that I have a class called Wheel and I want to store the user input related to both back wheels and then the two front wheels, then just display the whole info i stored in console.

It works entirely until it arrives to the last scanner for `frontwheels`, I write the input in console for it and it throws the `" scanner.ensureopen() line not available "` error, opening it in another window of eclipse and the program doesn't show me the info of `frontwheel` and doesn't finish as it should.
Here's my code:

WHEEL CLASS

```
package com.vehicles.project;

public class Wheel {
    private String brand;
    private double diameter;

    // Wheel Constructor 
    public Wheel(String brand, double diameter) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    public String infoWheel() {

        return "brand: " + brand + " and diameter: " + diameter;

    }
}
```

MAIN

```
package com.vehicles.project;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

import com.vehicles.project.*;

public class Main_Vehicles_Fase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your plate, car brand and color");

        Car userCar = new Car(sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Your plate is: " + userCar.plate + ", the brand is " + userCar.brand + " and the colour is "
                + userCar.color);


        System.out.println("Enter backwheels brand and diameter");

        Wheel userBackWheels = new Wheel(sc.nextLine(), sc.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Your backwheels info --> " + userBackWheels.infoWheel());

        System.out.println("Enter frontwheels brand and diameter");

        Wheel userFrontWheels = new Wheel(sc.nextLine(), sc.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Your frontwheels info --> " + userFrontWheels.infoWheel());

        sc.close();

    }
```

Comment: Is it your actual code? Does this very code produces the error you described? Do you close another `Scanner(System.in)` scanner anywhere else in your code?

Comment: It is not the entire code, i have another class named Car and another named vehicle, but the problem is only with the wheel class so i just copied that one and the main. I just close the scanner at the final of main, there isn't another close.

Comment: If you want help, post something we can reproduce.  [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't encountered error OP specified, usually we get this error if we close scanner. Looks like it is not closed in the main class based on OP's code.

```
scanner.ensureopen() line not available
```

I encountered different error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at com.vehicles.project.Main_Vehicles_Fase1.main(Main_Vehicles_Fase1.java:28)
```

I changed the parsing double logic. can you give a try. OP code is not perfect. I don't want to improve it because it might be a homework.

```
package com.vehicles.project;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_Vehicles_Fase1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your plate, car brand and color");

        Car userCar = new Car(sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine(), sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Your plate is: " + userCar.plate + ", the brand is " + userCar.brand + " and the colour is "
                + userCar.color);

        System.out.println("Enter backwheels brand and diameter");

        Wheel userBackWheels = new Wheel(sc.nextLine(), new Double(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Your backwheels info --> " + userBackWheels.infoWheel());

        System.out.println("Enter frontwheels brand and diameter");

        Wheel userFrontWheels = new Wheel(sc.nextLine(), new Double(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Your frontwheels info --> " + userFrontWheels.infoWheel());

        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks! but i will like to know why you add that "new double" if is possible, thanks!

Comment: @Jaykooh  The java.util.Scanner.nextDouble() method scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched. refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextdouble.htm